# Cancelling AlertDialog And Application

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am using a Activity, where I have declared ActionBar tabs and ViewPager .Every page is fetching data online and showing it in a ListView. I am showing a AlertDialog when there is no network connection.The  problem is AlertDialog is not getting cancelled in one click. There are six tabs and same ViewPager, after clicking  it six times its getting cancelled.

Below is the full code.

```
public class AlertDialogBox  extends DialogFragment{
Context mContext;
StartActivity sa;
public AlertDialogBox(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    sa =new StartActivity();
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    //alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Really?");
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Check your internet connection");
    //null should be your on click listener
   //alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            //dialog.dismiss();
            //mContext.
            //mContext.finish();
            sa.finish();

        }
    });


    return alertDialogBuilder.create();
}
}
```

Comment: what context r u passing?In this AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

Comment: reason of your problem is you are opening six dialogs. 
"I am showing a AlertDialog when there is no network connection." if i am getting your problem right.

Comment: I have used only one class for AlerDialog,but there are six ViewPager ,all extending Fragment class, data is fetched online simultaneously in all ViewPager.

Comment: @ jeevamuthu : I have posted the full code.

Comment: @ Amourreux :  I am not opening six dialogs, its because in all classes data are fetched simultaneously, and in each class I am checking Internet connection, so six dialogs are opening .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your checking of internet connection in main activity, not in each page. Also, show your dialog from main activity.

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Check your internet connection");       
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
     dialog.dismiss();
     finish();      

   }
});
return alertDialogBuilder.create();
```

}

Comment: @ Dimmerg : Just want to know where should I check internet connection? before declaring tabs and viewpager  or in viewpager adapter class, where I have used switch case to call each class containing listview.

Comment: I think on start your activity - before declaring tabs.